# Assign a unique key to repeated Arraylist items. and Keep track of Ordering in java

Tags: java, android, arraylist, key, string-comparison

I have a data like :

in an arraylist of Strings I am collecting names .

example:

souring.add(some word);
later I have something in souring = {a,b,c,d,d,e,e,e,f}

I want to assign each element a key like:

0=a

1=b

2=c

3=d

3=d

4=e

4=e

4=e

5=f

and then I store all ordering keys in an array . like:

array= [0,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5]

heres my code on which I am working :

```
 public void parseFile(String path){
    String myData="";

     try {

         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path)); {
             int remainingLines = 0;
             String stringYouAreLookingFor = "";

             for(String line1; (line1 = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
                 myData = myData + line1;

                 if (line1.contains("relation ") && line1.endsWith(";")) {

                     remainingLines = 4;//<Number of Lines you want to read after keyword>;
                     stringYouAreLookingFor += line1;

                     String everyThingInsideParentheses = stringYouAreLookingFor.replaceFirst(".*\\((.*?)\\).*", "$1");
                     String[] splitItems = everyThingInsideParentheses.split("\\s*,\\s*");
                     String[] sourceNode = new String[10];
                     String[] destNode = new String[15];
                     int i=0;

                     int size = splitItems.length;


                   int  no_of_sd=size;

                     tv.setText(tv.getText()+"size " + size + "\n"+"\n"+"\n");  

                     sourceNode[0]=splitItems[i];


// here I want to check and assign keys and track order...

                    souring.add(names);              


    if(size==2){
      destNode[0]=splitItems[i+1];   
      tv.setText(tv.getText()+"dest node = " + destNode[0] +"\n"+"\n"+"\n");

                 destination.add(destNode[0]);
         }
     else{
 tv.setText(tv.getText()+"dest node = No destination found"+"\n"+"\n"+"\n"); 
                     }

                 } else if (remainingLines > 0) {

                     remainingLines--;
                     stringYouAreLookingFor += line1;

                 }


             }
             br.close();



         }


     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }




}
```

How can I do this?

can any one help me in this..?

Comment: It is really hard to follow what you are trying to do and where your question is.  It is usually best try and break your problem down with where your code is running into problems or explicitly state what you are trying to accomplish.  Please edit your post for clarity.

Comment: i have edited the post kindly review it ... thanks

Comment: @Amstell  any idea how to solve this problem . I ve tried many things but unable to make it right .

Comment: any solution to this edited problem

Comment: The data structure you want is called a graph. Your unique property of this question is that edges have a property that they are labeled with a string.

Comment: yes exactly ... but the problem i am facing is i am extracting data dynamically and want to store it as graph data structure with string edge. but i have no idea how to implement it . any working example that matches this concept can help a lot .

Comment: let ignore the edge string ... but keys mapping in graph .. how can i implement graph data structure for collecting correct keys for from n to form.. in this above code

Comment: I edited the question . i think now i am asking the right question and following the right direction .. can anyone help in this

Comment: please help me in this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459152/compare-hashmap-string-value-and-duplicate-key-for-repeated-entry

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459152/compare-hashmap-string-value-and-duplicate-key-for-repeated-entry 


here is the solution to this problem . it has been solved by maps and hashmaps . see the link above .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use ArrayList instead of String[]

So, if you want to add an element you just write

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>;
list.add("whatever you want");
```

Then, if you want to avoid repetitions just use the following concept:

```
if(!list.contains(someString)){
   list.add(someString);
}
```

And if you want to reach some element you just type:

```
list.get(index);
```

Or you can easily find an index of an element

```
int index=list.indexOf(someString);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you want in step 2, but you can try to use HashMaps.
So basically you can type,like that
`HashMap<String,String> results;
results.put("animal","cat");
results.put("animal","dog");
results.put("building","house");`

Keys animal, building will not be repeated here.
If need something more you can use ArrayList<HaspMap<String,String>> or just keep the list of results in ArrayList and check new entries there, then if they are new put them into HashMap.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i have edited the question .. i hope it will clear it to you now .. i want to keep track of all elements which i am considering sources also repeated ones but with keys .. my above example will clear you what i want but dont know how to do it .. if any help in this regard will be appreciated.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give it a try, its take time to understand what you actually want.

```
    HashMap<Integer,String> storeValueWithKey=new HashMap<>();
    // let x=4 be same key and y="x" be new value you want to insert
    if(storeValueWithKey.containsKey(x))
        storeValueWithKey.get(x)+=","+y;
    else
        storeValueWithKey.put(z,y); //Here z is new key

    //Than for searching ,let key=4 be value and searchValue="a"
    ArrayList<String> searchIn=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(storeValueWithKey.get("key").split(",")));
    if(searchIn.contains("searchValue"))
```

If problem still persist than comment

Comment: i got what u are trying to do here appending the keys and then spliting . let me make it clear  :  Supose there is an array of repeated strings . i want to assign keys dynamicaly .. here i have to set z and x with defined values for keys . i want something it checks in for the same words and repeat its key the no of times repeated word comes in the list.

Comment: i also tried your code .. but it has a lot syntax errors too.

Comment: @Adnan Qureshi If you got syntax error than try to follow with comment, this code is written in rough without IDE.Now check out the updated answere. You mash with something,here key is unique value is appending. Your key is Unique and value vary isn't