# Compare Hashmap String value and duplicate key for Repeated entry

Tags: java, android, dictionary, arraylist, hashmap

I am using

```
Map<Integer, String> adi = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
for(int u=0; u< sari_nodes.size();u++){
    adi.put(u, sari_nodes.get(u));
}

for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : adi.entrySet()) {
    tv.setText(tv.getText()+"Key : " + entry.getKey()+ " Value : " + entry.getValue()+"\n");
}
```

My output is :

```
key: 0 Value : cat
key: 1 Value : dog    
key: 2 Value : car    
key: 3 Value : car    
key: 4 Value : car    
key: 5 Value : car
```

I want to repeat the key for same entry so that my output looks like

```
key: 0 Value : cat    
key: 1 Value : dog    
key: 2 Value : car    
key: 2 Value : car    
key: 2 Value : car    
key: 2 Value : car
```

How can I perform a check to get these kind of repeated keys?

Can somebody give me some guidance on solving this issue?

thanks.

Comment: You don't have your code that shows `sari_nodes`, possibly consider updating it to show this.

Comment: sari_node contains the words and repeated words , like car , dog , cat , room, any word or name and it can be many in size .. that is why i am storing them in an arrayList then geting them to store in an map as values

Comment: Why are you wanting to return `Key 2` for the remaining numbers of `u` in `sari_nodes.size()`? That seems redundant as you are excluding the other values in the list.

Comment: in fact u is just a for loop handler . i used it to assign a individual key . but i want to chek if repeated value comes for which a key already is been assigned like 2 for car and again the value car comes it should add 2 as key . i need to keep exact track of keys and in exact ordering

Comment: Side note: If you want uniqueness in a HashMap, swap your keys with values. Hashmap cannot contain duplicate keys. The latest value entered for a duplicate key will persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second the answer of [`NameSpace`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3126670/namespace).

You want every value to be unique. So, for that you can create a map which add value of your current map as a key. Ultimately we are trying to fetch the same key (first key) for same values. You can do it in a following way.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
map.put(1, "cat");
map.put(2, "dog");
map.put(3, "car");
map.put(4, "cat");
map.put(5, "dog");
map.put(6, "dog");

Map<String, Integer> uniqueValues = new HashMap<>();

for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    Integer key = entry.getKey();
    String val = entry.getValue();
    if (uniqueValues.containsKey(val)) {
        key = uniqueValues.get(val);
    }

    uniqueValues.put(val, key);
    System.out.println("Key : " + key + " - Value : " + val);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Key : 1 - Value : cat
Key : 2 - Value : dog
Key : 3 - Value : car
Key : 1 - Value : cat
Key : 2 - Value : dog
Key : 2 - Value : dog
```

*NOTE :* Case sensitive, in above code it will consider that `Dog` and `dog` both are different.

Comment: i got it the way ... works great .. thanks a lot... i really appreciate your knowledge .

Answer (score 1):

You would just make a second map, and as you iterate through the elements of the first map, flip the key-value to be the value-key of the second map.   If first map's value has already been added to second map as a key, do not overwrite, and output the key-stored-as-a-value in the latter, otherwise output the new key.

Comment: i am new to Hashmaps .. can u give any example how to implement it . and these values are dynamic there can more than 4 pair of repeating words . does all repeating values get identical keys with 2 maps..?

Comment: A hash map does not keep track of whether a value is associated with multiple keys, so one solution is to iterate through it checking which values are repeated.  

Adding the values of the first map as the keys into a second map lets you check which values are already used.   You would only write to the second map if the key has not been added yet.  You also appear to want to repeat the first key (or order value) from the first occurrence, which you could store here as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code below:

```
Map<Integer, String> adi = new HashMap<>();

adi.put(0, "cat");
adi.put(1, "dog");
adi.put(2, "car");
adi.put(3, "car");
adi.put(4, "car");
adi.put(5, "PC");

int lastKey = 0;
String lasValue = "";
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : adi.entrySet()) {
    if (!entry.getValue().equals(lasValue)) {
        lastKey = entry.getKey();
    }
    lasValue = entry.getValue();
    //tv.setText(tv.getText()+"Key : " + lastKey+ " Value : " + entry.getValue()+"\n");
    System.out.println("Key : " + lastKey+ " Value : " + entry.getValue());
}
```

And this is the output:

```
Key : 0 Value : cat
Key : 1 Value : dog
Key : 2 Value : car
Key : 2 Value : car
Key : 2 Value : car
Key : 5 Value : PC
```

Comment: I'd just point out this solution assumes all his repeated values appear consecutively.

Comment: a great solution ... for consecutive repetitions.